# MYSQL - multi-dimensional array - loop or recursion?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

In my MYSQL database, I have 2 tables:

```
+-------------------+  +---------------------------------+
|       tags        |  |          relationships          |
+----+--------------+  +---------+---------+------+------+
| id | tag          |  | x_table | y_table | x_id | y_id |
+----+--------------+  +---------+---------+------+------+
| 1  | parent 1     |  | tags    | tags    | 1    | 2    |
| 2  | child 1      |  | tags    | tags    | 1    | 3    |
| 3  | child 2      |  | tags    | tags    | 3    | 4    |
| 4  | grandchild 1 |  +---------+---------+------+------+
+----+--------------+
```

I need to load these relationships into a multi-dimensional array. The number of children can change and the depth can change. The depth is also different for each relationship tree.

Now I've read that recursive functions are slower than loops for interpreted languages like PHP, and was wondering if it would even be possible to write this with loops, and if so, if it would be faster and less resource intensive than using a recursive function?

The structure of the multi-dimensional array should be as follows:

```
array(
    'id' => $id_from_db,
    'tag' => $tag_from_db,
    'children' => array( /* Just like parent array or false/NULL */ )
)
```

**EDIT:** [SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c217)

**EDIT:** I created the recursive function to achieve this:

```
private function get_tags($id = false){
    global $pdo;
    $tags = array();

    if(!$id)
        $info = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT
                    t.id,
                    t.tag

            FROM    tags t
            JOIN    relationships r
            ON      r.x_table = 'tags'
            AND     r.y_table = 'tags'
            AND     t.id NOT IN ( SELECT rb.y_id FROM relationships rb WHERE x_table = 'tags' AND y_table = 'tags' )

            ORDER BY t.tag");

    else
        $info = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT
                    t.id,
                    t.tag

            FROM    tags t
            JOIN    relationships r
            ON      r.x_table = 'tags'
            AND     r.y_table = 'tags'
            AND     r.x_id = " .(int)$id."
            AND     r.y_id = t.id

            ORDER BY t.tag");

    while($tag = $info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        $tags[] = array('tag' => $tag['tag'], 'children' => $this->get_tags($tag['id']) );

    if(!count($tags))
        return false;

    return $tags;
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot `y_id = 2` row in relationships table.

Comment: can you provide an example of your tables on sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: They're MYSQL tables, not HTML tables.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy he said, sqlffiddle not jsfiddle.

Comment: My apologies. That's what I get for not reading. [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a [little help from Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887634/mysql-multi-dimensional-array-loop-or-recursion/16900822#answer-16900822), I was able to come up with the code:

```
public function get_tags(){
    global  $pdo;
    $tags = $childs = array();

    foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM tags')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $tag)
        $tags[$tag['id']] = $tag;

     foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE x_table='tags' AND y_table='tags'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $relationship){
        if(!isset($tags[$relationship['x_id']]['children'])) 
            $tags[$relationship['x_id']]['children'] = array();       

        $tags[$relationship['x_id']]['children'][] = &$tags[$relationship['y_id']]; 

        $childs[] = $relationship['y_id'];
    }

    while($childs)
        unset($tags[array_pop($childs)]);

    return $tags;
}
```

This returns my requested array with the exception that the children element simply doesn't exist if there are no children (which is actually better than setting it to false).

**Benchmarks:**
I ran a simple `time php file.php > /dev/null` using each of the functions, and the results showed that using the loop took a total of `0.751s`, whereas the recursion took a total of `1.303s`. This was looping through a small set of data though. Based on how the code is structured, I'd hypothesize that the recursion would take exponentially longer as the data set increased whereas the execution time of the loop would increase in a linear fashion.

All in all, I'd say that looping is significantly faster than recursion.

Answer (score 3):

You could use references if you don't mind fetching everything in 1 go (2 queries) (probably the total amount of tags should be below a couple of hundred, and you could cache the resulting construct for a while):

```
 //fill tags
 $tags[] = array()
 foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM tags')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $tag){
    $tags[$tag['id']] = $tag;
 }

 //add relationships
 $relation_query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM relationships 
   WHERE x_table='tags'  AND y_table = 'tags'");
 foreach($relation_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $relationship){
   //ensure targets exists:
   if(!isset($tags[$relationship['x_id '])) $tags[$relationship['x_id '] = array();
   if(!isset($tags[$relationship['y_id '])) $tags[$relationship['y_id '] = array();

   if(!isset($tags[$relationship['x_id ']['children'])) 
     $tags[$relationship['x_id ']['children'] = array();       

   //add as reference
   $tags[$relationship['x_id ']['children'] = &$tags[$relationship['y_id ']; 
 }

 //pick the tag you want:
 var_dump($tags[1]);
 var_dump($tags[4]);
```

Not that a [`closure` table](http://karwin.blogspot.nl/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) , or just [path enumeration](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)(slide 18 onwards, but the whole thing is worth a read) will give you even bigger performance, and the possibility to just query for a subtree. Big props to Bill Karwin.

Comment: This is an interesting and clever approach. I'm not sure I understand it completely and I must leave for work soon, but I'll play with this after work and see if everything plays out the way I think it does. Also, what's the difference between a closure table and my relationship table? Is it the fact that mine also holds the table names?

Comment: A closure table has the entry not only of every direct parent, but of every ancestor (so reversed, also of every grandchild and further). This means a _much bigger_ table, but you gain the overhead of inserting back in extreme quick returns of an entire subtree (no recursion needed).

Comment: I see. I don't think I'd need that for this project, but I'll definitely keep that in mind. As far as the code goes, I was able to come up with something that did exactly what I wanted thanks to you. I'll post my end result along with benchmarks and accept it as the answer since this didn't do exactly what I wanted, but I'll give you credit for giving me a helping hand.